# Sqlite can't connect to database from inside jar: NullPointerException ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jar

My connect code:

```
private Connection connect(String dbpath)  {
        try  {
            Connection conn;
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" +
                    dbpath + ".db");
            System.out.println("Good!");
            return conn;
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
dbpath = /home/username/stuff.db
```

It runs OK when I run from Idea Intellij, but when I package in jar it fails.

EDIT:

This is the error more down the stacktrace:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

[image]

Comment: It would be good to at least do `e.printStackTrace()` as that will give you more detail about the error. But if `dbpath = "/home/username/stuff.db"` then note you'll have `*.db.db` after your string concatenation.

Comment: I'll try it! But .db doesnt get appended, it's 100% just 1 .db. It works when I run from IDE, only doesn't work from JAR

Comment: Based on your edit you appear to have forgotten a dependency when deploying your application. You could ship the dependency jars with your jar or create a fat/uber jar.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> } catch (Exception e)  {
>    System.out.println("Error!");
>    return null;
> }
> ```

This is a 'doctor, it hurts when I smash this hammer in my face repeatedly' problem.

Stop doing that.

The proper way to handle an error is to handle it (logging it, isn't handling it). The next best way is to throw the exception onwards (here, add `throws SQLException` to your method signature. It is entirely sensible for a method that is designed to connect to a DB, to do that). If you can't do that either, the proper handler is `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);` - because your way, well, leads to exceptions that no longer provide the information you need. You've tossed out all interesting parts. Most likely that db path isn't there (you are in a different directory), or possibly the CLass.forName call failed because your dependencies are broken.

Normally, the exception would tell you exactly which of these two cases is the problem.

But, because you wrote the snippet I showed above, now you don't. Thus, proving that snippet is bad. The solution is simple, though. Don't write code like that ever again :)